# ContentProvider sometimes returns non-existing images

Tags: android, android-contentprovider, android-gallery, android-loader

I created an activity for multi image picker. Images are requested via Loader like this:

```
@Override
public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int id, Bundle args) {
    String[] projection = {
        MediaStore.Files.FileColumns._ID,
        MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.DATA
    };

    switch (id) {
        case IMAGES_LOADER:
            String selection;
            String[] selectionArgs;
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 16) {
                selection = MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.SIZE + ">100 and " +
                    MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.WIDTH + ">? and " +
                    MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.HEIGHT + ">?";
                selectionArgs = new String[] { String.valueOf(mMinWidth), String.valueOf(mMinHeight) };
            } else {
                selection = MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.SIZE + ">0";
                selectionArgs = new String[0];
            }

            return new CursorLoader(this, MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
                projection, selection, selectionArgs,
                MediaStore.Images.Media._ID + " desc"
            );
        default:
            return null;
    }
}
```

After that I load images to ImageViews via UIL like this:

```
String data = cursor.getString(mDataColumnIndex);
try {
    mImageLoader.displayImage(Uri.fromFile(new File(data)).toString(), holder.image);
} catch (Exception e) {
    …
}
```

But sometimes in catch block it appears `FileNotFoundException`. I logged such file names, checked them in file manager, they really not exist.

This is piece of log about one file with this effect. File manager doesn't show it, but its size and dimensions were successfully loaded from ContentProvider:

```
… Displaying image [/storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Camera/IMG_20150703_195503.jpg], size 2448 x 3264, file length 1418535 (ImagePickerActivity.java:241)
… Showing uri: [file:///storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Camera/IMG_20150703_195503.jpg] (ImagePickerActivity.java:253)
… /storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Camera/IMG_20150703_195503.jpg: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
    java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Camera/IMG_20150703_195503.jpg: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
            at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:456)
            at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:76)
            at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:103)
            at com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.download.BaseImageDownloader.getStreamFromFile(BaseImageDownloader.java:142)
            at com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.download.BaseImageDownloader.getStream(BaseImageDownloader.java:78)
            at com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.decode.BaseImageDecoder.getImageStream(BaseImageDecoder.java:83)
            at com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.decode.BaseImageDecoder.decode(BaseImageDecoder.java:69)
            at com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.LoadAndDisplayImageTask.decodeImage(LoadAndDisplayImageTask.java:307)
            at com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.LoadAndDisplayImageTask.tryLoadBitmap(LoadAndDisplayImageTask.java:262)
            at com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.LoadAndDisplayImageTask.run(LoadAndDisplayImageTask.java:128)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
     Caused by: android.system.ErrnoException: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
            at libcore.io.Posix.open(Native Method)
            at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.open(BlockGuardOs.java:186)
            at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:442)
            at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:76)
            at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:103)
            at com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.download.BaseImageDownloader.getStreamFromFile(BaseImageDownloader.java:142)
            at com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.download.BaseImageDownloader.getStream(BaseImageDownloader.java:78)
            at com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.decode.BaseImageDecoder.getImageStream(BaseImageDecoder.java:83)
            at com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.decode.BaseImageDecoder.decode(BaseImageDecoder.java:69)
            at com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.LoadAndDisplayImageTask.decodeImage(LoadAndDisplayImageTask.java:307)
            at com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.LoadAndDisplayImageTask.tryLoadBitmap(LoadAndDisplayImageTask.java:262)
            at com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.LoadAndDisplayImageTask.run(LoadAndDisplayImageTask.java:128)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

Why such items are returned? How to avoid this?